# The address has an invalid host name. Decoded string is not a valid IDN name. Parameter name: unicode

Tags: c#, smtp

Getting this error for mail address that looks completely normal. Any help would be appriciated.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The address has an invalid host name: DAAIRMAN23@GMAIL.COM‏. ---> System.ArgumentException: Decoded string is not a valid IDN name.
Parameter name: unicode
   at System.Globalization.IdnMapping.GetAsciiUsingOS(String unicode)
   at System.Globalization.IdnMapping.GetAscii(String unicode, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.Globalization.IdnMapping.GetAscii(String unicode, Int32 index)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetHost(Boolean allowUnicode)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetHost(Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetAddress(Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetSmtpAddress(Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ValidateUnicodeRequirement(MailMessage message, MailAddressCollection recipients, Boolean allowUnicode)
   **at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)**
```

Every adress is transformed to utf8 using this function:

```
public static MailAddress toUtf8(this MailAddress address)
{         
   return new MailAddress(address.Address?.ToUpper(), address.DisplayName, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: My bet, the address has an unicode character which seems normal ascii but it's not.

Comment: Bet some code would help

Comment: `DAAIRMAN23@GMAIL.COM‏.` -> does the address actually end with a `.`? If so, that's illegal and is likely the actual cause.

Comment: @Gusman I'm actually trying to transfer address to utf8 using toUtf8 method mentioned in question. I think this should solve unicode problems, am I right?

Comment: @jstedfast Dot (.) is part of error message, that's for sure.